# Is there a js console emulator that provides access to the browsers 'real' javascript console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, terminal, terminal-emulator

Does anyone know of any console emulator (preferably made in javascript or jquery) that would allow me direct access to the browsers javascript console that would be found in the developers tools in chrome for example? I have been using [jq-console](https://github.com/replit/jq-console) but that only emulates a terminal, very useful so far. However it only *emulates* a terminal and doesn't provide access to the browsers js console. I need this so that users have a front-end web based access to the console without having to open the developer tools or something similar, so they have access to the variables and objects available in the browsers js console. I had thought of loading the data into the memory of the jq-console instance however i think this would be a cumbersome process and i don't really know how to go about doing it without the information being directly entered into the jq-console instance. any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason you can't actually use the dev console itself?

Comment: Did you look into the `console` instance and what methods it has?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's a _javascript terminal_? Do you mean console?

Comment: @Cerbrus - I am creating a game to help teach people about programming and I want the users to have a nice clean web front to work with, while I wouldn't consider opening and using the dev console an advanced task I don't think it is the easiest solution for people just learning a programming language.

Comment: @Joe: That's a fair enough reason :P

Comment: @AaronDigulla -with jq-console you accept input and then it is your to do with as you please, there are no methods for the console, as you define them your self and determine which to use based on the input

Comment: @jrummell - yes i do, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @mortb - So say i have a player object in my game (i should mention its all written in ImpactJS so javascript) I can open my dev tools and type ig.game.player and get all the information about the object printed out. I would like to do that but in front-end web interface. I just had a thought though I guess i could use eval to evaluate their code and return the info but that would leave the application vulnerable as eval is evil or so i've heard, any thoughts?

Comment: I would hope that any user capable of learning javascript is able to press `F12` or `Ctrl-Shift-J` in any modern browser. :)

Comment: the simplicity of opening the dev console isn't the point as i mentioned earlier. I am trying to provide a solution that is conducive to the learning process. Take CodeAcademy.com for example. They could have users just use the js console but they opted for a cleaner solution in a web-based front end console and that has served them to no ends. Its about providing a learning environment and i think the dev console (which includes a lot of unnecessary tools for the scope of my project) takes away from that environment. that said i understand where you're coming from.

Comment: ps no disrespect meant, i just want to make something worth while and i think if i told users okay play this game but you have to  keep opening and closing the console (which takes up valuable space in the browser) would be sub par work on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> direct access to the browsers javascript console

No. Not without opening the console manually, and also you cannot do much more than logging messages. Any emulator will not use the native console.

> web-based front end console at CodeAcademy.com

Have you looked at their source code? You can write such one yourself, too. Or have a look at EloquentJavaScript's [console script](http://eloquentjavascript.net/js/ejs.js) (using Mochi and Codemirror).

> a browser console

…is not possible without only emulating it. However, you can use [FirebugLite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) for that, which promises the same look-and-feel as the native Firebug. Also, Opera's [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) is written in JS, and it is [released as open source](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/development/) so you might adapt (parts of) it.